# Convert String to date Objective-C

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, date

I have seen the other answer and question but i didn't find any useful answer for me.
I have a string like `2014-10-07T07:29:55.850Z` and I want to have a date to compare each other.
If I use this code:

```
 NSString *fullDate = payload[@"sent_ts"];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:fullDate];
```

My date is nil. Why?

Comment: You have a dot after the seconds...not a colon.  Look more carefully at your format string before you post a question ><

Comment: I've seen that but unfortunately it isn't the error.

Comment: Put single quotes around the T

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try This.

```
 NSString *dateString =  @"2014-10-07T07:29:55.850Z";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: @fustalol - the Z is a valid time formatter:   http://www.deanoj.co.uk/ios-development/nsdateformatter-formatting-strings-reference/

Comment: This is a good reference for the date formatter. https://nsdateformatter.com