# Having difficulty sorting this array

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want to sort by a string that appears in different place in each array object.

I have an nsarray that contains objects like this:

```
Jones John 05-12-1993 Diabetes *05-13-2019 **R ***No Data ****68xxx

Smith John 05-12-2019 Hypertension *05-12-2019 **R ***05-12-2019 ****117xx

Smithers John 05-12-1947 COPD *05-13-2019 **R ***05-13-2019 ****89xxx

Wilson John 05-13-2019 Atrial Fibrillation *05-13-2019 **R ***05-16-2019 ****90xxx

Davis Joe 05-23-1905 Hypertension *05-25-2019 **R ***05-23-2019 ****42xxx
```

I need to sort the array by the date after the single asterisk. I cannot figure out how to do this. I've tried a number of example but it doesn't work.  Any suggestions? Thanks.

I have tried this and of course it only sorts by the beginning of each object

```
[self.nameAndDOB sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]; // 1-5 sort patient roster by last name
```

Comment: You have to extract the date string (preferable with Regular Expression) and sort that. Or even better parse the string into  a custom class with appropriate properties

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to use a real Custom object, not a String like that. An object with a Name, Surnam, Birthday(?) Date, Analysis? Date, Symptoms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: is a method that compares strings. It obviously doesn't compare them the way you want. Your challenge, should you accept it, is to write a method that compares strings in the way *you* want them to be compared and pass the selector of the method to sortUsingSelector:

I usually use one of the block-based sorting methods; easier to write and more flexible.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please add a sample code snippet?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following things

- Extract the date from the string, you have to do according to your algorithm or Regular Expression.
- [Convert the string to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230792/convert-string-to-date-objective-c)
- [Compare Date](https://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-compare-two-nsdates/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to extract the date string, convert it to a date, and cosort on it. Like this:

```
let array = [
    "Jones John 05-12-1993 Diabetes *05-13-2019 **R ***No Data ****68xxx",
    "Smith John 05-12-2019 Hypertension *05-12-2019 **R ***05-12-2019 ****117xx",
    "Smithers John 05-12-1947 COPD *05-13-2019 **R ***05-13-2019 ****89xxx",
    "Wilson John 05-13-2019 Atrial Fibrillation *05-13-2019 **R ***05-16-2019 ****90xxx",
    "Davis Joe 05-23-1905 Hypertension *05-25-2019 **R ***05-23-2019 ****42xxx"
]
let patt = " \\*\\d\\d\\-\\d\\d\\-\\d\\d\\d\\d"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: patt, options: [])
let f = DateFormatter()
f.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
let array2 = array.map { s -> Date in
    let r = 
        regex.firstMatch(in: s, options: [], range: NSRange(s.startIndex..., in: s))!.range
    let ss = 
        (s as NSString).substring(with: NSRange(location: r.location+2, length: r.length-2))
    return f.date(from:ss)!
}
let sorted = zip(array,array2).sorted{$0.1 < $1.1}.map{$0.0}
```

The result is

```
[
    "Smith John 05-12-2019 Hypertension *05-12-2019 **R ***05-12-2019 ****117xx", 
    "Jones John 05-12-1993 Diabetes *05-13-2019 **R ***No Data ****68xxx", 
    "Smithers John 05-12-1947 COPD *05-13-2019 **R ***05-13-2019 ****89xxx", 
    "Wilson John 05-13-2019 Atrial Fibrillation *05-13-2019 **R ***05-16-2019 ****90xxx", 
    "Davis Joe 05-23-1905 Hypertension *05-25-2019 **R ***05-23-2019 ****42xxx"
]
```

... which I think you'll agree is the right answer based on what you've said.

However, as others have said, the original problem as posed is silly. You should not be dealing with these structured strings in the first place. You should parse them into a custom struct, right at the start, and work with instances of that struct instead.

Comment: I think you missed that the question is tagged objective-c which lacks direct equivalents of `map`, `zip` and tuples; and the custom struct advice may not be so applicable. Decent Swift answer though.

Comment: @CRD I missed nothing. Language is irrelevant. NSRegularExpression and NSDateFormatter are part of Foundation. I described a technique and showed that it can work.

Comment: OK, glad you missed nothing just trying to be helpful. However unless we're going to debate at the level of Turing completeness I must differ and say language is *not* irrelevant. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks. I know about the structure and there are many ways to skin the cat, but I am dealing with a fix to a legacy app, so for now, I need to deal with the hand I was dealt ;)

Comment: This concept looks like it will work, however I know nothing about swift. can anyone reproduce this in Objc.  I'd be most appreciative. thanks.